# Adding data from multiple checkbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

This is my add form. [image]
I have multiple check box with yes/no. My problem is I don't know how to get the values chosen by the user and save it to db.

I have a sample code but this one is only for one check box

```
If checkbxname.Checked = CheckState.Checked Then
   checked = 1
   'insert query
Else 
   checked = 0
   'insert query
End If
```

Comment: The answer is in your question `[checkbox ID].Checked` will give you the value selected by the user. What have you tried, put in your code and specify whats happening and what do you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

As the @TheUknown said:

```
If checkbxname.Checked = CheckState.Checked Then
   checked = 1
   'insert query
Else 
   checked = 0
   'insert query
End If
```

Answer is above.
Every each checkbox has a different name. Instead of `checkbxname` use your other checkboxes names to check if those are selected or they are not.

For example if you have checkbox called `checkboxhasjobyes`:

```
If checkboxhasjobyes.Checked = CheckState.Checked Then
   checked = 1
   'insert query
Else 
   checked = 0
   'insert query
End If
```

That said I believe you do not need checkboxes for yes or no type of questions.. Radio buttons in groups would be much more useful. Checkboxes are best used when something is optional. With yes/no or any choice type of questions radiobuttons would be preferred at least at simple level.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and advice.. I think I should change it to radio buttons.. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   If chkYes.Checked = True Then
            MsgBox("Yes")
        Else
            MsgBox("No")
        End If
```

Checkbox checked event it's like boolen type so you need to check True or False

Answer (score 0):

It is inappropriate to use 2 Checkbox as yes or no, It would be better if you use 1 Checkbox and use this code:

```
Dim checked As Integer = 0
If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
   checked = 1
Else
   checked = 0
End If
```